# How can I print every four fields on a new line using awk?

Tags: r, awk

When I export a large size R output in to a text file it distort the appearance of the out put. so i need to export it properly as it looks the out put in R. Could you give me a solution?

Here is the data looks like:

```
4 546.5 1 0.995012  
4 542.5 2 0.990050
4 539 3 0.985112
4 535 4 0.980199
10 488 1 0.995012
10 490.5 2 0.990050
10 470.5 3 0.985112
10 472 4 0.980199
```

I wanted to fit separate model and get the regression coefficients for each ID ($1) using $2 as response variable and $3 and $4 as explanatory variables.
I got an output like this:

```
Call:
   Model: weight ~ dim + expdim | id 
   Data: sample 

 Coefficients:
   (Intercept) 
    Estimate Std. Error     t value  Pr(>|t|)
4    633.5365   284123.2 0.002229795 0.9984233
10 17237.8328   284123.2 0.060670276 0.9571391
   dim 
    Estimate Std. Error      t value  Pr(>|t|)
4   -4.211269   1403.006 -0.003001604 0.9978776
10 -89.465142   1403.006 -0.063766745 0.9549559
  expdim 
      Estimate Std. Error       t value  Pr(>|t|)
4     -83.29169     284141 -0.0002931351 0.9997927
10 -16741.62918     284141 -0.0589201546 0.9583733

   Residual standard error: 6.961743 on 2 degrees of freedom
```

I used the following code to export my output but it distorted it.

```
output <- capture.output(summary(m2))
cat("My title", output, file="m2.txt", sep="n", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: What is the object you're trying to output? Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Are you sure that the `sep="n"` is correct? Without knowiung anything about R, I would try to use `sep="\n"`, or at least lookup the documentation and examples on that command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs`.

Having this file:

```
$ cat m2.txt
538.8915   7.514458  71.71395  0.000000e+00n10    482.6413   7.782459  
62.01655  0.000000e+00n22    523.8301   8.799187  59.53165  0.000000e+00n27
```

**Result**

```
$ xargs -n4 <m2.txt
538.8915 7.514458 71.71395 0.000000e+00n10
482.6413 7.782459 62.01655 0.000000e+00n22
523.8301 8.799187 59.53165 0.000000e+00n27
```

From `man` page:

> ```
>  -n number
>          Set the maximum number of arguments taken from standard input for each invocation of utility.
> ```